# Sharepoint 2013 Popularity trends Empty Values

Tags: 2013, web-analytics

I want to see the usage reports but the excel reports shows all zeros (In site settings > Popularity Trends )

**Debuuging** 
I checked and both the timer jobs "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Import        Minutes, "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Usage Data Processing" are running 
In search crawling I used to have Scheduled Crawling  but i changed it  to continuously ,then also i am not seeing any results

Also in search i am load balancing which is i have 2 Query Servers and 1 Index Server .
Is there a way i can check the logging DB ?Can you please suggest me how can I make it work or whats the best debugging process

Comment: In the usage and health settings in Central a Admin, make sure you have activated logging for this information

Comment: Yes its already there ..

Comment: I am also facing the same issue. Dd you get any solution for this.

Comment: Thanks a lot i was able to fix it .I posted my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First i ran the below command and it didn't gave any output

```
Get-SPTimerJob -Type Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.UsageAnalyticsJobDefinition | Select *
```

Which is when i found the issue and after going through a bunch of Blogs .This below Powershell Script did the trick for me

```
$ssa = get-spenterprisesearchserviceapplication "search service application"
$ssa.Status = “Disabled”
$ssa.Update()
$ssa.Provision()
```

Once this completes.. run the below command again

```
Get-SPTimerJob -Type Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Analytics.UsageAnalyticsJobDefinition | Select *
```

You will see that now it will give output  and then from the next day i was able to see the analytics in the Excel Reports

Answer (score 2):

I ran into similar situation before.  It was working for awhile and all of the sudden it stopped.  I noticed there wasn't anything logged to the Usage database and the log folder in the 15 Hive (default location) has a very old modified date.  The timer jobs and event handlers were all in place.

What ended up fixing my problem is to change to file log location from 15 Hive to somewhere else, say /_log folder.  After that I can see logs starts populating in the file system and also in the database.

Comment: Do you have to change the logs any where in sharepoint? And how long does it take to populate once after the logs folder is changed? Thanks